# How to use different predefined 3D matrices per time step in a function file containing a differential equation to be solved by ode 45

Tags: matlab, matrix, parameter-passing, ode, differential-equations

I would like to evaluate the differential equation in matrix form `dvdt = -(A - B*inv(R)*B'*S)'*v - Q*rd` using ode45, where `A`,`B`,`Q` and `R` are time varying matrices, `rd` is a constant row vector and `v` is the variable to integrate. This equation is defined in a function file. On the other hand, the 3D matrix `S = S(:,:,250)` is obtained independently of time in the calling file. The problem is that in my equation function I need to use each one of the matrices S for every time step in ode45 (e.g. `S(:,:,1)` for time step 1, `S(:,:,2)` for time step 2, `S(:,:,3)` for time step 3, etc). I was wondering if you could advice me about how can I perform this process. The function file is:

```
function dvdt = myfun(t,v,S)
A = A(t); B = B(t); R = R(t); Q = Q(t);
dvdt = -(A - B*inv(R)*B'*S)'*v - Q*rd;
end
```

and the calling file is simply:

```
S = S(:,:,250); % Defined previously in this file
[t,v] = ode45(@(f,v) myfun(t,v,S),f,v0);
```

Thanks in advance.